# Mysql print all rows via php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mysql and I have a table called players with 3 entries. I need to display players names in a page via php. I am using folowing code:

```
$isplayer = "SELECT name FROM players";
$isplayer2 = mysql_query($isplayer) or die("Could not query player table.");
$isplayer3 = mysql_fetch_array($isplayer2);

foreach(array_unique($isplayer3) as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

I am getting only 1 result, not 3. What's wrong? I want to print all players' names.

Comment: mysql is deprecated. use PDO or mysqli

Comment: Maybe you only have one player?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way to display these records is as follow, you are newbie thats why

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM players");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $row["name"];
}
```

Comment: @siride You are right. But the user is a newbie. he must have connected using mysql not by PDO

Comment: @Indra: so show the user the right way to do things. This is a simple enough question that there's unlikely to be gobs of existing code all using mysql_ instead of PDO or mysqli_.

Comment: @siride the user already mentioned that i am newbie, what's wrong to direct him the same way he wants? if he can't manage simple code how come he will manage PDO?

Comment: @MoxetKhan: it's never right, in any field, to say "don't bother doing the right thing because you're a newbie". Would that be okay in carpentry? Don't bother with safeties or proper procedures. Just start using bandsaws as best you can. No, that would not be okay. We shouldn't condone this type of teaching. You just have to learn the right way, period.

Comment: @siride don't compare carpentry with programming, the are totally different and i hope the user got his answer.

Comment: @MoxetKhan: why not? Why is it not okay for us to ask programmers to know what they're doing when programming? Why is it not okay to ask people to follow safe practices? In the age of heartbleed and buffer overflow attacks (still!), I think it's all the more important to ask our programmers to program properly. Real money is at stake.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this

```
$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players");

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
       echo $row["name"]."<br>";
          }
```